# simple Nginx config not working

Tags: nginx, server, config, linode

i am a developer with absolutely no server experience, this project im working on is my first foray into the world of servers. Basically i have to host an API online, on a Linode server running Nginx on Ubuntu. And im having trouble getting a simple server block set up to host a html index page, with just a h1 tag saying 'hello'. I've followed and read various tutorials on getting a simple server block working, i've even got these blocks working on my local machine, but im having issues getting it to work on the remote server.

il show you some blocks that have failed to work for me on the Linode:

first, a simple block to server a static html page, this works on my local machine:

```
server {

    listen 8005;
    index index.html;
    root /srv/www/site;

}
```

another simple block:

```
server {

    listen [server ip]:8006;
    server_name "";
    index index.html;
    root /srv/www/site;

    location ~/ {

        root /srv/www/site;

    }

}
```

a block for serving php (works locally):

```
server {

    listen [server ip]:8007;
    server_name "";
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    root /srv/www/site;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

    }

    location ~* \.php$ {

        try_files $uri /index.php;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;

    }

}
```

whenever i tried to access them through the browser i got server connection timeouts. I do not have any DNS setup with it so i was trying to access it using the server IP and port number:

or

but got nothing.

So one thing that might cause the problem is the fact that another application is being hosted on the server already. It has its own block and is running on its own port. It has its own DNS name pointing to it. But none of this should matter right? as each server block is basically a virtual server or creates a virtual domain. Accessing it through ip and port should work fine, but it aint working!

thats about all i can think of, my knowledge in this area is maxed out and i need help from smart people!

any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: have you checked whether nginx is actually running (on the ports configured)? also try setting `listen` to `[ip]:[port] default_server;`, `servername` to  `_;` and restart nginx

Comment: thanks, yeh i've checked that nginx is listening to those ports, i've also added your suggested lines but got no results. Am i right in saying that the other application should not cause interference with my new server blocks, and a should be able to access them through the browser with [ip]:[port] if all is set up fine? cheers